# custom herald action phabricator

Tags: php, phabricator

I'm trying to create a custom herald action, by extending the `HeraldAction.php` and dropping my file in the `phabricator/src/extensions` directory, [**as explained here**](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/).

For my first try, I simply wanted to do as in the example, by adding the `ExampleApplication.php` file :

```
final class ExampleApplication extends PhabricatorApplication {
    public function getName() {
        return pht('Example');
    }
}
```

The thing is I get this error when reloading my phabricator web UI after :

> [Core Exception/PhutilBootloaderException] Include of extension file
>   '/srv/phabricator/src/extensions/ExampleApplication.php' failed!

What am I doing wrong? 
I am not trying to create a library for the moment, but only dropping it in the extension directory doesn't seem to work for me...

Thank you for your help,

Yann

Comment: Please show minimum code sufficient to reproduce

Comment: So we can help you, edit your question and put your source code into a code block.   Then the code is human readable

Comment: @ScottStensland I edited my question, thank you for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's me again.

I found the solution to my own problem... Since the error log wasn't very explicit, I tried changing several things and one worked : it was a permission problem...

I gave all rights to my extension directory for everyone :

```
chmod -R 777 extensions/
```

I also tried adding a library folder, and faced the same permission problem.

That did the trick.

Thank you anyways :)

Yann